# How to correctly use super().__init__ when passing arguments?

Tags: python, class, oop

I am relatively new to OOP in python and am making a little program to get me started. The problem is that when I create an object, no matter how many positional arguments I use, I seem to have an error with the number of arguments.

As I'm fairly new to this area of programming, I'm not quite sure what to try, but I have attempted to play around with the attribute initialising stages, however, that completely disables the program.

#### The program:

```py
import random


class character:
    def __init__(self, name, skill, brains, home, strength, force):
        self.name = name
        self.skill = skill
        self.brains = brains
        self.home = home
        self.strength = strength
        self.force = force


class force_user(character):
    def __init__(self, name, skill, brains, home, strength, force, dark_force, light_force):
        super().__init__(self, name, skill, brains, home, strength, force)
        self.dark_force = dark_force
        self.light_force = light_force


class jedi(force_user):
    def __init__(self, name, skill, brains, home, strength, force, dark_force, light_force, master, rank):
        super().__init__(self, name, skill, brains, home, strength, force, dark_force, light_force)
        self.master = master
        self.rank = rank


a = jedi('Yoda', 46, 17, 'Dagobah', 34, 97, 2, 10, "N'Kata Del Gormo", 'Grand Master')
```

#### Errors:

When I have the `'Grand Master'` 'rank' argument in object 'a', I receive this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File [file directory], line 37, in <module>
    a = jedi('Yoda', 46, 17, 'Dagobah', 34, 97, 2, 10, "N'Kata Del Gormo", 'Grand Master')
  File [file directory], line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(self, name, skill, brains, home, strength, force, dark_force, light_force)
TypeError: __init__() takes 9 positional arguments but 10 were given
```

and when I remove the `'Grand Master'` argument, I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File [File Directory, line 37, in <module>
    a = jedi('Yoda', 46, 17, 'Dagobah', 34, 97, 2, 10, "N'Kata Del Gormo")
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rank'
```

I don't quite understand the problem myself, but any help or advice would be great!

Comment: You don't need to pass `self` to the super class, that's basically something `super()` takes care of. As a rule of thumb, you barely ever explicitly pass `self` to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change

```py
super().__init__(self, name, skill, brains, home, strength, force, dark_force, light_force)
```

to

```py
super().__init__(name, skill, brains, home, strength, force, dark_force, light_force)
```

You don't need to pass `self` (the first argument) when using non static instance methods.

To be extra clear: if you had this method in `jedi`

```py
def printName(self):
    print(self.name)
```

you would simply call it with `a.printName()`, not `a.printName(a)`.

Comment: Corentin Pane: I knew it would be a simple answer - thanks so much!